# Use of undeclared type 'Element' In Swift Extension Method (Array)

Tags: ios, swift, generics, namespaces, protocols

I am using Generics and protocol to make a name space for my Utils Class. and here when I goes to [Array] , I met some problem . here is the code :

in namespce.swift:
[image]
and in Array Extention:
[image]
can any one tell me how can i fix it?

---

Update: 
I change my code to :
[image]

and here I have another problem , I have use "Self" in the function. but the T: Sequence type has no member of "index" .

Comment: It would be better if you can include the actual code instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here (and if it's still relevant) but you should constrain your generic to `RangeReplaceableCollection` (to be able to use `remove(at:)`) instead of `Sequence`.
The `firstIndex(of:)` method (which returns the index of the first matching element) is available on `Collection` where `Element: Equatable`.

```
extension JX_TypeWrapper where T: RangeReplaceableCollection, T.Element: Equatable {
  mutating func remove(object: T.Element) {
    if let index = SELF.firstIndex(of: object) {
      SELF.remove(at: index)
    }
  }
}
```

Which allows you to wrap an array into your `JX_TypeWrapper`:

```
var array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
var wrapped = JX_TypeWrapper(value: array)
wrapped.remove(object: 2)
wrapped.SELF // [1, 3]
```

Comment: thanks , I have tried your function, it worked. But if I just want to use `ary.ext.remove(object: 3)` what should i do?